# Can't use the multiple prop in Autocomplete while also using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use the Multiple prop with Autocomplete in Material UI. But every time I try to add it in it breaks my code. Seems to have an issue with my onChange prop, but I cannot figure out how to make them work together. Basically I am trying to display multiple values as well as the information inside the array on my page. Here is my code below. Thanks in advance!

```
type Movie = {
  label: string
  year: number
}

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | null>(null)
  
  console.log({ movie });

  return (
    <Grid container padding='32px'>
      <Stack direction='row' spacing={2} divider={<Divider orientation='vertical' flexItem sx={{ width: 'auto' }} />}>
        <Autocomplete
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        options={top100Films}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params}
        label='Skills' />}
        value={movie}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: Movie | null) => setMovie(newValue)}
        />
        <Paper sx={{ width: 300 }} elevation={4} >
          <Typography fontSize='40px'> {movie === null?"": movie.label} </Typography>
        </Paper>
        <Paper sx={{ width: 300 }} elevation={4}>
          <Typography fontSize='40px'>
            {movie === null?"": movie.year}
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Stack>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: what error it is throwing??

Comment: I get 2. The error under the value prop is: Type 'Movie | null' is not assignable to type 'Movie[] | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Movie[] | undefined'.  The error under the onchange prop is Type '(event: any, newValue: Movie | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: Movie[], reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<Movie> | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'newValue' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Movie[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Movie': label, year